# How to continuously record sets of 4 seconds with AudioRecord

Tags: java, android, audio-recording, android-audiorecord

I'm trying to record sets of 4 seconds from the AudioRecord, process them and than record again and so on. I'm recording at 44100 samples/second, you can see in the code below. I have to mention that I record, or at least I should record sets of pulses of 19Khz.

```
    int frequency = 44100;
                int blockSize = 44100;
                int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
                int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

                final int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);

                audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, frequency, channelConfiguration,
                        audioEncoding, blockSize * 8); // if I multiply blockSize by 4 it will only give 88200 buffer size

                // start recording until explicitly stopped
                while ( <stopCondition> ) {
                    recData = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(recData);
                    short[] buffer = new short[blockSize * 4]; // Save the raw PCM
//                  timePassed = false;
//                  timer.cancel();
//                  timer.start();
                    audioRecord.startRecording();
//                  while (!timePassed) {
                        int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, blockSize * 4);
                        for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                            try {
                                dos.writeShort(buffer[i]);
//                              buffer[i] = 0;
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
//                  }

                    audioRecord.stop();
                    try {
                        dos.flush();
                        dos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
... process the recorded data
```

As you can see from the code (commented) I have tried using a countDownTimer which stops the recording after 4 seconds have passed. It was only reading from audioRecord 1 second at a time (the blockSize wasn't multiplied by 4), but I didn't know exactly if the buffer gets overridden, since the offset is 0 - I assume it does but I'm still not sure :) Using this approach it didn't record the number of pulses played in 4 seconds - 16 pulses played, only 2-3 recorded.

Than I tried without the timer and read from audioRecord blockSize * 4 = 44100 (=1s) * 4 = 4s, but in Audacity I see only 1 second being recorded - somewhere in the code, not shown here, I write the recorded data to a file to check the output. Again number of recorded pulses are not ok, but that's obvious since I have only 1 second of recorded data.

Is there a better way of continuously recording sets of X seconds and process them? Or if my approaches are ok than what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to below code.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startRecording();
            }
        }, 4000);
```

**startRecording Method**

```
private void startRecording() {
    myFilename = getFilename();
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**getFilename**

```
private String getFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm-ss");
    String currentDateandTime = sdfDate.format(new Date());

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + currentDateandTime + file_exts[currentFormat]);
}
```

This will start new recording each after 4 seconds and getFilename will give name to your recording as currentDate and time.

Hope you are looking same what i understood from your question still if i miss understood you then please correct me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I don't think using MediaRecorder will help me. I don't see where you specify the sample rate, the audio enconding and so on. What I do after recording a set of 4 seconds is convert the raw byte data into a double array and apply an IIR filter and other processing. I only write files to check each step of the algorithm, and that's working fine. My problem is that I'm not sure if the buffer contains all the recorded data or just part of it.